# sed not behaving properly w/ capture group; can't see what's wrong

Tags: regex, bash, sed

Sorry to have to post this as it seems rather basic, but I can't tell why the heck it's not working:

```
sed -r -i.bak 's/-- Database: (.*?)\n/CREATE DATABASE \1\n/g' file.sql
```

The file contains a line that looks like this:

```
-- Database: `omptest`
```

and doing the exact same thing as a find/replace in sublime works fine:

```
Find: -- Database: (.*?)\n
Replace with: CREATE DATABASE \1\n
```

sed doesn't seem to like the \1 unless I either escape the parentheses surrounding the capture group or use -r for expanded regex -- otherwise it throws sed: -e expression #1, char 53: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS.

Regardless, when I use the -r or escape the parentheses, it doesn't edit the file, as though it hasn't worked. I have no idea why.

I think I'm either forgetting or just now discovering some weird property of sed regex but I can't for the life of me figure out what the issue might be. Help appreciated!

Comment: Yes, in basic regex mode, you need to escape the parentheses of a capture group. Is that your question? If not, what are you asking?

Comment: @TomFenech if you add `-r`, you do not need to escape parentheses.

Comment: @Jotne, yes, I know! :) That would be extended regex mode. Still, it is unclear what is being asked here.

Comment: d'oh. clarified that it's not making the edits.

Comment: It can't be stressed enough that there is no such thing as "a regex" since all the tools that work on "regex"s use different syntax from each other and have various capabilities and caveats. Does your tool support EREs or BREs or PREs? How about capture groups, backreferences, character classes, escape sequence abbreviations for character classes? Do any non-regex metachars also have meaning (e.g. sed delimiters)?  To use a regex in a tool you need to first learn the regex syntax and capabilities FOR THAT TOOL and not assume that some regex you used in some other tool will work the same way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sed` works on a line-based basis and doesn't see the newlines in a file (unless you do special things). Use

```
#                                 vvv----------------vvv--- no newlines
sed -r -i.bak 's/-- Database: (.*?)/CREATE DATABASE \1/g' file.sql
```

**Addendum:** Three more things to note, perhaps:

1. `.*?` does exactly the same as `.*` in sed. The former can be used for non-greedy matching in some other regex engines but not in sed. The `?` does not do any harm, but it doesn't do anything at all either.
2. Since the regex matches greedily to the end of the line, the `/g` flag doesn't have any impact. There's never going to be a second match because the first extends to the end of the line.
3. Since the capture group is put right back where it was found, it doesn't really need to be captured it in the first place.

From the first two observations, we might arrive at a simplified version of the original script:

```
sed -r -i.bak 's/-- Database: (.*)/CREATE DATABASE \1/' file.sql
```

...and because of the third, we could ditch those changes again and just use

```
sed -i.bak 's/-- Database: /CREATE DATABASE /' file.sql
```

instead.

Comment: THANK YOU! that explains it perfectly.

Comment: If you want to be sure you go all the way to the end of the line then you should anchor it with `$` at the end, either just before or just after the closing paren.

Comment: Well, the regex is greedy, so that isn't necessary (does no harm, either). The `?` is likewise superfluous (but does no harm), come to think of it, since the Kleene star already allows an empty match. EDIT: As is the `/g` option. In fact, it would be possible to just use `s/-- Database: /CREATE DATABASE /` and have the same effect.